# AVL-tree in Pascal: rotation results in Error 202--stack overflow; why?

Tags: pascal, avl-tree

The following code for implementing AVL-tree insertion & deletion gives **error #202 (stack overflow)**.

Source code looks like this:

```
program Avl_generator; uses Crt;

type p_Avl = ^Avl_node;
 Avl_node = record
 key: integer;
 l, r, par: p_Avl; {pointers to left child, right child, parent}
 bal, h: integer {balance factor, height}
 end;

procedure init(var root: p_Avl); begin new(root); root:=nil end;

function get_height(var n: p_Avl): integer;
begin
  if(n=nil) then get_height:=-1 else get_height:=n^.h;
end;

procedure reheight(var n: p_Avl); {refresh the height variable}
begin
  if(n<>nil) then
  begin
    if(get_height(n^.r)>get_height(n^.l)) then n^.h:=1+get_height(n^.r)
      else n^.h:=1+get_height(n^.l);
  end;
end;

procedure set_balance(var n: p_Avl); begin reheight(n); n^.bal:=get_height(n^.r)-get_height(n^.l); end; {refresh the balance factor}

function rotate_l(var a: p_Avl): p_Avl; {left rotation, a is pivot}
var b: p_Avl;
begin
  b := a^.r;
  b^.par := a^.par;
  a^.r := b^.l;
  if(a^.r<>nil) then a^.r^.par := a;
  b^.l := a;
  a^.par := b;
  if(b^.par<>nil) then
    if(b^.par^.r=a) then b^.par^.r := b
      else b^.par^.l := b;
  set_balance(a); set_balance(b);
  rotate_l := b;
end;

function rotate_r(var a: p_Avl): p_Avl; {right rotation, a is pivot}
var b: p_Avl;
begin
  b := a^.l;
  b^.par := a^.par;
  a^.l := b^.r;
  if(a^.l<>nil) then a^.l^.par := a;
  b^.r := a;
  a^.par := b;
  if(b^.par<>nil) then
    if(b^.par^.r=a) then b^.par^.r := b
      else b^.par^.l := b;
  set_balance(a); set_balance(b);
  rotate_r := b;
end;

function rotate_l_r(var a: p_Avl): p_Avl; {left & right rotation, a is pivot}
begin
  a^.l := rotate_l(a^.l);
  rotate_l_r := rotate_r(a);
end;

function rotate_r_l(var a: p_Avl): p_Avl; {right & left rotation, a is pivot}
begin
  a^.r := rotate_r(a^.r);
  rotate_r_l := rotate_l(a);
end;

procedure rebalance(var root: p_Avl; var n: p_Avl); {refresh balance factors and see if sub-trees need rotating}
begin
  set_balance(n);
  if(n^.bal=-2) then
  begin
    if(get_height(n^.l^.l)>=get_height(n^.l^.r)) then n:=rotate_r(n)
      else n:=rotate_l_r(n);
  end
  else if(n^.bal=2) then
  begin
    if(get_height(n^.r^.r)>=get_height(n^.r^.l)) then n:=rotate_l(n)
      else n:=rotate_r_l(n);
  end;
  if(n^.par<>nil) then rebalance(root, n^.par) else root:=n; {recursion here}
end;

procedure insert(var root: p_Avl; what: integer);
var found: boolean;
  pre_tmp, tmp: p_Avl;
begin
  found:=false; tmp:=root; pre_tmp:= nil;
  while(tmp<>nil) and not found do
    if(tmp^.key=what) then found:=true
      else if(tmp^.key>what) then begin pre_tmp:=tmp; tmp:=tmp^.l end
      else begin pre_tmp:=tmp; tmp:=tmp^.r end;

  if not found then
  begin
    new(tmp); tmp^.key:=what;
    tmp^.l:=nil; tmp^.r:=nil; tmp^.par:=pre_tmp; tmp^.h:=0; tmp^.bal:=0;
    if(pre_tmp=nil) then root:=tmp
      else
      begin
        if(pre_tmp^.key>what) then pre_tmp^.l:=tmp else pre_tmp^.r:=tmp;
        rebalance(root, pre_tmp);
      end;
  end;
end;

procedure delete(var root: p_Avl; what: integer);
var found: boolean;
  tmp, pre_tmp, act, pre_act: p_Avl;
begin
  found:=false; tmp:=root; pre_tmp:=nil;
  while(tmp<>nil) and not found do
  begin
    if(tmp^.key=what) then found:=true
      else if(tmp^.key>what) then
        begin pre_tmp:=tmp; tmp:=tmp^.l end
      else
        begin pre_tmp:=tmp; tmp:=tmp^.r end;
    if found then
      if(tmp^.l=nil) then
      begin
        if(pre_tmp=nil) then root:=tmp^.r
          else if(pre_tmp^.key>what) then pre_tmp^.l:=tmp^.r
          else pre_tmp^.r:=tmp^.r;
        dispose(tmp); rebalance(root,pre_tmp);
      end else if(tmp^.r=nil) then
      begin
        if(pre_tmp=nil) then root:=tmp^.l
          else if(pre_tmp^.key>what) then pre_tmp^.l:=tmp^.l
          else begin pre_tmp^.r:=tmp^.l end;
        dispose(tmp); rebalance(root,pre_tmp);
      end else
      begin
        act:=tmp^.l; pre_act:=nil;
        while(act^.r<>nil) do begin pre_act:=act; act:=act^.r end;
        tmp^.key:=act^.key;
        if(pre_act=nil) then begin tmp^.l:=act^.l; dispose(act); rebalance(root,tmp) end
          else begin pre_act^.r:=act^.l; dispose(act); rebalance(root,pre_act) end;
      end;
  end;
end;

var Avl_tree: p_Avl;
begin
  init(Avl_tree);
  insert(Avl_tree,1);
  insert(Avl_tree,2);
  insert(Avl_tree,3);
  insert(Avl_tree,4);
  insert(Avl_tree,5);
  writeln(get_path(Avl_tree, 5));
  repeat until KeyPressed;
end.
```

This compiles fine (Turbo Pascal 7.0). When I run the code, though, the error occurs in the **rotate_l** procedure which is called **after the third insertion** (whereupon balance factor of the root node =2.

I checked some Java & C++ implementations and the rotation methods there seemed quite similar to mine, therefore I don't know where the problem is..?

Comment: Try walking through the code with debugger

Comment: Hi Devstr, thanks (sorry, new to Pascal). I tried adding watches for **a** & **b** and by the second line `b^.par := a^.par`, **a** was net to _nil_. Therefore, it cannot be dereferenced in `a^.par := b`; so there is some problem with my deferencing in general here. What problem, I haven't figured out yet.

Comment: Yep, I got the same when running turbo pascal in dosbox.

Comment: Stack overflow errors usually happen if you have a never-ending recursion in your code. Make sure there are proper ending conditions that stop it at some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's been 14 years since I touched Pascal last time :)

So the problem is indeed with `rotate_l` function. 
You are passing `a` parameter **by-reference** as indicated by `var` keyword.

```
     rotate_l(var a: p_Avl)
```

That causes `a` to become nil when you overwrite `b.par`, 
Because `a` **references** the address of `b.par` in that particular function invocation and you set `b.par` to nil. 
So `a` now is referencing memory location that contains nil.

You need to change function signature to pass `a` parameter **by value**. This is done by removing `var` keyword.

```
    rotate_l(a: p_Avl)
```

---

Stack overflow is caused by the same issue in `rebalance` procedure:

Change

```
procedure rebalance(var root: p_Avl; var n: p_Avl);
```

to

```
procedure rebalance(var root: p_Avl; n: p_Avl);
```

---

See Free Pascal language reference for parameters 
http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Parameters

Comment: Never occurred to me, thank you very much. There's still some problem with the recursion never ending, but I suspect I'll figure that one out (that one is not within the scope of this question, anyway).

Comment: If you get stuck you can submit another question. But try thoroughly debugging first. Also in this case I would recommend visualising the tree on each step in order to understand what is happening.

Comment: @davnovak: the never-ending recursion is the cause for the stack overflow, which **is** the question (according to the title), AFAICT. Accessing nil is not.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I've updated the answer with the fix for never-ending recursion. It was the same issue with passing parameter by reference.